# What would happen if someone could remotely manipulate atoms?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, super-powers, chemistry, nuclear

Those of you who are familiar with the DC Comics hero Firestorm know that he can alter the chemical structure of any form of inorganic matter, provided he knows the chemical equation. In my story, I want to make a character similar to this, but perhaps from a more believable standpoint.

To be honest, I'm not that knowledgeable in chemistry (yeah I know, then why am I asking, right?), but I do know that chemical reactions are used to make chemical compounds and rearrange atoms. For my character's power, let's say they don't have to worry about the energy requirements to remotely manipulate atoms and molecules, but still have to take into account the other laws of physics, such as conservation of matter, and the different types of atomic bonds (ionic, metallic, and covalent). I assume that because every element has its own atomic number, its own electron configuration, its own atomic weight, its own crystal structure, and its own physical state, etc, this would make the manipulation more complicated. I also know that because of these specifications, it'd be harder to transmute one element or compound into another element or compound. There is also the chance of radiation being produced because of this, which could be deadly

I know to you guys, it probably sounds I'm overlooking a lot of basic chemistry or atomic principles, but please bear with me. My question is ultimately **what would need to happen for any form of matter to transform into another form of matter while upholding the laws of physics (except the energy requirement and the fact that it can be done remotely through the mind) and what would the results or consequences from doing such be?**

Comment: Its a bit overpowered but since the character is using their mind they could control the electromagnetic force and re arrange atoms to their liking.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but surely there's gotta be more to it than that, right? I mean what about where the unused atoms would go?

Comment: Nanotechnology would be far easier. An experienced chemist could create just about any material with their mind. Potentially it would cause a revolution in materials production and engineering.

Comment: @Galaxy I was going to suggest nanotech also, but could they transform matter at a high speed like a super power?

Comment: @Strivs im not sure if any left over atoms can be a small amount of radiation. or just turn them into air or something else.

Comment: Also for architecture, you could create arbitrarily large structures using the mind alone at an astonishingly fast rate, giving you the ability to create fantastical sci-fi palaces. You can build anything you want, provided you know it's molecular structure.

Comment: The question is, do you have to manipulate every single atom independently, or can you automate the process? If you have to think about every single atom, then producing macro scale structures becomes very tedious.

Comment: Atoms are held together by the strong nuclear force so messing with with the electromagnetic force won't change their atomic structure. Air is made of atoms. If you really want to make them powerful why not abandon the law of conservation of mass as well and be done with it?

Comment: Oh Yeah that's true, electromagnetism on its own can't change atomic structures.

Comment: Are you talking about changing one element to another or simply rearranging molecules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For “any form of matter to be converted into any other form of matter” either all of the elements required in the product are present in the correct quantities to start with or it would require nuclear processes to transmute one element into another, in which case you just need to have sufficient mass.

The result of nuclear transmutation would be a large quantity of radiation depending on the nuclear reactions used and the degree of magic involved.

Comment: This reminds me of my dr manhattan question where it turns out it would be like an atomic bomb going off when he dis assembled and re assembles his matter.